# React - Webpack module.exports require

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, module

Watching the Webpack course for React.js on YouTube, the author of the video showed the `content.jsx` file where `require` and `module.exports` are used

[image]

saying that "using require we link to the react folder and also for react-dom, then export the Content class", my question is why, instead of require, it does not use import `React from 'react'` for react-dom `import React from 'react- dom'` and export `export Content` or `export default Content`

Comment: Because the course is out of date, sloppy, wrong? Webpack has had built in ESM support for years now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the tutorial you are watching is using Webpack 1 which uses the older CommonJS module format. `require` was how people imported stuff, and `module.exports` was how they exported stuff. Now a days CommonJS isn't used as much for frontend development because ES modules are being used more often and support [tree shaking](https://h.shadowtime2000.com/what-is-es6-tree-shaking-1) (that is a link to an article I wrote on the topic).

Comment: Based on the URL of your link containing your user name, you appear to have linked to your own site/a site you're affiliated with. If you do, you *must* disclose that it's your site in your post. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).

Comment: @Nick, Thanks for letting me know, I have given a note that I wrote that article.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Please do read the linked articles; if you post too many links to your website it may still be considered as spam even with disclosure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that is, I can use the new syntax `import React from 'react'` instead of `require`?

Comment: @Synchro Probably, most modern bundlers support ES modules. That of course only works if you are using a bundler.